# Create mutating set for Index in Collection subscript in Swift

Tags: swift, collections, subscript

I'm trying to modify this extension in order to get mutability:

```
extension Collection where Element: Equatable {
    
    /// Returns the element at the specified index iff it is within count, otherwise nil.
    subscript (safe index: Index) -> Element? {
            indices.contains(index) ? self[index] : nil
    }
}
```

I want to achieve this working:

```
var array = ["Hello", "World"]
array[safe: 5] = "Other word" // This will not be setted because index is out of bounds, but error won't be throwed.
```

When I try to modify the subscript extension...

```
extension Collection where Element: Equatable {
    
    /// Returns the element at the specified index iff it is within count, otherwise nil.
    subscript (safe index: Index) -> Element? {
        get {
            indices.contains(index) ? self[index] : nil
        }
        mutating set {
            if indices.contains(index) {
                self[index] = newValue        <<<-- ERROR
            }
        }
    }
}
```

... I get this error: `Missing argument label 'safe:' in subscript`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Collection`'s [`subscript`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection/1641358-subscript) is get-only.

[`MutableCollection`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/mutablecollection) is the protocol that `Array` conforms to, that declares the [settable `subscript`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/mutablecollection/1640969-subscript) that we all know and love. After all, your extension requires the collection to be mutable, and not all `Collection`s are mutable, only `MutableCollection`s are.

```
extension MutableCollection {
    
    /// Returns the element at the specified index iff it is within count, otherwise nil.
    subscript (safe index: Index) -> Element? {
        get {
            indices.contains(index) ? self[index] : nil
        }
        mutating set {
            if indices.contains(index), let value = newValue {
                self[index] = value
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I also added a check in the setter for the case when `newValue == nil` (because the subscript has type `Element?`, you can assign `nil` to it!). In that case, the subscript won't do anything. The `Element : Equatable` constraint is also not needed.

---

Technically, this can also be done on `RangeReplaceableCollection`s, which is another one of those protocols that `Array` conforms to. But subscripts are supposed to be O(1) time, and `replaceSubrange` isn't necessarily so.

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection {
    
    /// Returns the element at the specified index iff it is within count, otherwise nil.
    subscript (safe index: Index) -> Element? {
        get {
            indices.contains(index) ? self[index] : nil
        }
        mutating set {
            if indices.contains(index), let value = newValue {
                self.replaceSubrange(index...index), with: CollectionOfOne(value))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sublime explanation

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `Collection` has no mutable subscript setter. To get that, you need to extend `MutableCollection` instead.

```
extension MutableCollection where Element: Equatable {
    /// Returns the element at the specified index iff it is within count, otherwise nil.
    subscript(safe index: Index) -> Element? {
        get {
            indices.contains(index) ? self[index] : nil
        }
        mutating set {
            if indices.contains(index), let value = newValue {
                self[index] = value
            }
        }
    }
}
```